# Does github need SSH authentication even for public repositories?

Tags: github, ssh

I have noticed if I attempted to clone even a public GitHub repository over SSH from a machine where SSH keys are not present or misconfigured, github throws a `Permission denied (public key)` error.

The same works when I use HTTPS protocol.

Why is it needed to authenticate over SSH even for public repositories?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it needed to authenticate over SSH even for public repositories?

Before even before cloning, Git delegates to SSH, which  will attempt to resolve `git@github.com` (`ssh -Tv git@github.com`): if that fails, the rest of the clone does not proceed.

With an HTTPS URL, git delegates to curl which attemps to resolve https://github.com: no authentication is required there, so the rest of the clone command do proceed (unless GitHub objects, when accessing a private repository).